# Simply connected covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

"Find an example of a path connected, locally path-connected space which does not have a
simply connected covering space".
 I was reading hatcher and he gives an example of shrinking wedge of circles, and in exercise 5 he mentioned the comb space ,both  being spaces with no simply connected covering space, but these two spaces are not locally path connected, so can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: The Hawaiian earring (shrinking wedge of circles) *is* locally path-connected.

Comment: On the other hand, the Hawaiian earring is not semi-locally simply connected. A space must have this property in order to have a universal cover.

Comment: I said it doesn't have a simply connected covering space therefore "not semi-locally simply connected" so the hawaiin earrings are the appropriate example,I didn't knew it is locally path connected

Comment: @MikeMiller i can't see how it's locally path connected it looks like the comb space to me ,can you tell me how to see it ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go and have a look at my answer for this following question in math overflow.... link : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111310/universal-covering-space-for-non-semilocally-simply-connected-spaces/173250#173250